# What mistake did I make? Source engine reskin issues

Tags: modding, shading, source-engine, rendertexture

Here is a reskin of the Half Life 2 Wallace Breen model that I made for a mod I am developing, but the checkerboard on the suit is very odd. All my other skins have no issue, but this skin has checkerboards under certain lighting situations. When mat_fullbright 1 is on, chekerboards do not show. When dynamic shadows and shading in on, or when mat_fullbright 0 is in use, the suit checkerboards.[image]

[image: Checkerboard issues]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing one of your textures.

The source engine, when it can't find a specific texture, instead shows a checkerboard of purple and black squares, the different settings probably mean that a specific texture isn't loaded.

From looking around a bit the only references I can find to the settings and cvars you've mentioned are about lighting, I think you are missing a light map in your material.

Answer (score 1):

Your model most likely has incorrect normals (pointing inward) in some places. If you made this in Blender, I know there's like a [recalculate normals button](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18887) that should have them all going the correct direction.